# add data labels to stripchart

Tags: r, label, stripchart

I have made a stripchart with a threshold marked in red. I would like to label the point that falls to the left of the threshold, but can't seem to get the 'text' function working at all.

[stripchart screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZavGh.png)

Here is the stripchart code: 
`` stripchart(ctrls$`Staining Green`, method="jitter", pch=4, xlab='Staining Green', cex.lab=2) 
abline(v=5,col=2,lty=3) ``

I first tried to filter only those samples below the threshold:
`Staining.Green <- filter(QCcontrols, Staining.Green < 5)`
then adding the text with 
`` text(Staining.Green$`Staining Green` + 0.1, 1.1, labels = Staining.Green$Sample_Name, cex = 2) ``
This didn't add any text to the chart.

Then I tried labeling all the points, in case I was making it too complicated, with variations on:
`` text(ctrls$`Staining Green` + 0.1, 1.1, labels = ctrls$Sample_Name) ``
Again, no text added, and no error message.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Update: my ctrls object is more complex than I realized - maybe this is tripping me up:

````
List of 17
 $ Restoration                 : num [1:504] 0.0799 0.089 0.1015 0.1096 0.1092 ...
  ..- attr(*, "threshold")= num 0
 $ Staining Green              : num [1:504] 25.1 23.5 21.1 19.7 22.3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "threshold")= num 5
 $ Staining Red                : num [1:504] 39.8 40.9 36.9 33.2 33.2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "threshold")= num 5.......```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example using the built in data set for `airquality`:

```
stripchart(airquality$Ozone,
           main="Mean ozone in parts per billion at Roosevelt Island",
           xlab="Parts Per Billion",
           ylab="Ozone",
           method="jitter",
           col="orange",
           pch=4
)

abline(v = 5, col = 2, lty = 3)

with(subset(airquality, Ozone < 5), text(Ozone, 1.1, labels = Ozone))
```

**Plot**

[image: example stripchart with text labels]

**Data**

The lowest values of `Ozone` are:

```
head(sort(airquality$Ozone), 5)
[1] 1 4 6 7 7
```

**Edit**:

Here's a quick demo with a list with a similar structure:

```
vec1 <- c(0.0799, 0.089, 0.1015, 0.1096, 0.1092)
attr(vec1, 'threshold') <- 4

vec2 <- c(25.1, 3, 21.1, 19.7, 22.3)
attr(vec2, 'threshold') <- 5

ctrls <- list(Restoration = vec1, `Staining Green` = vec2)

stripchart(ctrls$`Staining Green`, 
           method="jitter", 
           pch=4, 
           xlab='Staining Green', 
           cex.lab=2
)

abline(v=5,col=2,lty=3)

text(ctrls$`Staining Green`[ctrls$`Staining Green` < 5], 1.1, labels = ctrls$`Staining Green`[ctrls$`Staining Green` < 5])
```

Note: Instead of explicitly including 5 for threshold you can substitute the `threshold` from your list attribute:

```
attr(ctrls$`Staining Green`, "threshold")
[1] 5
```

**Plot**

[image: stripchart]

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you, but with this line ```with(subset(ctrls, `Staining Green` < 5), text(ctrls, 1.1, labels = `Staining Green`))``` I get the error ```object 'Staining Green' not found``` . The airquality is a dataframe whereas my ctrls object is a list (in fact 17 lists, with thresholds as attributes). I tried converting it with as.data.frame but then the stripchart fails in the first line.

Comment: my update above is the output of ```str(ctrls)```, so Staining Green is one of 17 lists in the object, containing 504 numbers.

Comment: ["Staining.Green" was my attempt to subset on a separate line, but that's not needed if I'm adapting the airquality code.]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I will play with the positioning of labels, but that works :)